# How to convert value from checkbox bool to string can someone help me ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am doing MVC ASP.NET app and I am newbie to this please can someone tell me how to convert value from checkbox bool into string and where to do this into partial class or into controller ?[Checkbox mark is shown in my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f0sV.jpg)

```
    // GET: InspekcijskeKontrole/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.InspekcijskoTijeloId = new SelectList(db.InspekcijskoTijeloes, "InspekcijskoTijeloId", "NazivInspekcijskogTijela");
        ViewBag.ProizvodId = new SelectList(db.Proizvods, "ProizvodId", "NazivProizvoda");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: InspekcijskeKontrole/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "InspekcijskoTijeloId,ProizvodId,DatumInspekcijskeKontrole,Rezultat,ProizvodSiguran,InspekcijskaKontrolaId")] InspekcijskaKontrola inspekcijskaKontrola)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.InspekcijskaKontrolas.Add(inspekcijskaKontrola);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.InspekcijskoTijeloId = new SelectList(db.InspekcijskoTijeloes, "InspekcijskoTijeloId", "NazivInspekcijskogTijela", inspekcijskaKontrola.InspekcijskoTijeloId);
        ViewBag.ProizvodId = new SelectList(db.Proizvods, "ProizvodId", "NazivProizvoda", inspekcijskaKontrola.ProizvodId);
        return View(inspekcijskaKontrola);
    }
```

Comment: you want to convert boolean to string ? why not call `ToString()` method on your boolean value ?

Comment: I want to write something like the product is safe when checkbox is true

Comment: Sorry ! What does that mean  ? Why you think calling `ToString()` on a boolean value will make your product unsafe ?

Comment: I want in my new view to write something like "product is safe" on this place in table instead this mark when I check my checkbox on create View Can I make convertor I am new to ASP.NET

Comment: If you want to show that string(based on the boolean value from table), just do an if condition in your view and if that specific property value is true, print your specific text. Did you try that ?

Comment: No I am trying right now

Comment: Thx man it was in the view I solved it

Comment: To mark a question as solved, please simply tick ("accept") an answer below. To do so, click the tick mark adjacent to the answer that you find most helpful. If there is no such answer, feel free to make one.

Answer (score 1):

```
internal string GetProductState(bool checkboxValue)
{
    return checkboxValue ? "Your Product is safe": " Your product is not safe?";
}
```

Pass your checkbox value to method and print return value to related field

Comment: Should I make this method in JQuery sorry I am newbie in MVC or I tried to get element by id and to get his value?

Comment: And I should write this method in controller sorry I am totally new I will try anyway thx man?

Comment: Is it just front-end info ? Don't you need this on back-end at all ? Then you can of course make this in jQuery. it is all about arcitacture. The code above is written on c# by the way

Answer (score 0):

1) The cleanest way to do this is to have a seperate, static extension class.

eg.

```
namespace WebFrontend.Utils
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public static class WebExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
        {
            return html.DisplayFor(expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model));
        }
    }
}
```

2) You now have to create a ascx (web user control) view with the following content

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Boolean>" %>
<%: Model ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

3) In the view itself, you import this namespace.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="WebFrontend.Utils" %>
```

4) Now you can call it in your view like:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.BoolValue)%>
```

5) WARNING: This is quite static (output is always the same). If you have multiple different booleans, you will need to extend the function so that you can add the parameters (2 strings - perhaps as custom attributes in the model?) it should show. Alternatively you can do as following in the view:

```
<%: Model.BoolValue ? "This product is safe." : "This product is not safe" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ToString()` methods on your boolean value from the Model. You can do this in controller action method.

Comment: Please read the comments under the question. The OP wants to print a string (_"the product is safe"_) when a some bool property is `true`.

Answer (score -1):

The [Boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx)  has a `ToString()` method. So:

if you want to make some condition based on the checkbox and If you are using `Custom Model`, you can do something like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "InspekcijskoTijeloId,ProizvodId,DatumInspekcijskeKontrole,Rezultat,ProizvodSiguran,InspekcijskaKontrolaId")] InspekcijskaKontrola inspekcijskaKontrola)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {           
    if(inspekcijskaKontrola.chkTest == true)
    {
       inspekcijskaKontrola.responseText = "product is safe";
    }
    else 
    {
       inspekcijskaKontrola.responseText = "product is not safe";
    }
  }
}

public class inspekcijskaKontrola
{
   public bool chkTest { get; set; }
   public string responseText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I try this doesnt show nothing I have two classes one for server validation and other one is `[MetadataType(typeof(InspekcijskaKontrolaMeta))]
    public partial class InspekcijskaKontrola
    {
        public string responseText;
    }` and i did the same thing in contoller but nothing